# What is the corresponding way for adding in a bunch of custom gradle scripts, similar to applying plugins?

Tags: android, gradle

Inside of the app level gradle, we can do something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    ...
}
```

However, I've got a few custom gradle scripts that I'd like to apply. At the moment, I can copy each of these underneath that block, something like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/helpers/common-methods.gradle"
```

Which works fine, but I was wondering if there's a corresponding block/closure type of method for adding these, something like:

```
foo {
   from: "$rootDir/gradle/helpers/common-methods.gradle"
}
```

I don't particularly *need* this, was just interested

Comment: I don't know too much about gradle really, I have a few custom scripts but nothing major, if this is a duplicate, i'm sorry :)

Comment: I think you [should be able to use apply as a closure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware.html#N10C03) (read: `apply { from: ... }`)

Comment: Hi @Zoe, i've actually tried messing around with it before posting the question, finally found something which works, suppose i might as well make this a Q&A now

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found an answer.

```
apply {
from "$rootDir/gradle/helpers/common-methods.gradle"
}
```

make sure you use a space and don't use `from:`

using `from:` will give you a nice verbose error:

```
Statement labels may not be used in build scripts.
In case you tried to configure a property named 'from', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.
```

in this case, solution was to just use a space